# Is there a Windbg command for retrieving the module_name of a dump?

Tags: c++, debugging, module, filenames, windbg

I'm working with `windbg`, using a script that I found somewhere on the internet, for investigating dump files of a C++ application.

That script launches two commands: one to determine all symbols, present in the dump (at least that's what I think), and one for showing the memory addresses and types of all variables.

The first command: `x /2 *!*`

The result contains entries like:

```
0042da68          <application>!CMap<int,int,CStringArray *,CStringArray *>
...
74c06448          mfc110u!CStringArray
```

The second command is more complicated and gives following results:

```
006cabe0    <application>!CMap<int,int,CStringArray *,CStringArray *>
...
006f0280    mfc110u!CStringArray
```

I'm interested in the size of the `CMap` and `CStringArray` objects, so I'm launching following commands:

```
dt <application>!CMap<int,int,CStringArray *,CStringArray *> m_nCount 006cabe0
dt <application>!CStringArray m_nSize 006f0280
```

This is working fine, I get the information I need.
Also this seems to be working fine:

```
dt CStringArray m_nSize 006f0280
```

But this one is failing:

```
dt CMap<int,int,CStringArray *,CStringArray *> m_nCount 006cabe0
```

This means that I need to get the name of the application of the dumpfile (it seems to be gone during some formatting).

I can retrieve this using the `!analyze -v` command (do a `grep` on `MODULE_NAME`), but this looks a terrible burden just to get the name of the application.

Does anybody know the `windbg` command I need to run in order to know the application of the dump I'm investigating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable being debugged can be found with `|`:

```
0:000> |
.  0    id: 13ac    create  name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

However, that executable name may significantly differ from its module name:

```
0:000> lm m note*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
01150000 013bf000   notepad__   (no symbols)
```

From the output of `lm`, we can see that there are addresses associated with the module. If we would be able to map the entry point to a particular module, we would have a solution.

Luckily, there is `$exentry` which gives us the entry point and `lm` accepts an address with `lm a <address>`, so we have:

```
0:000> lm a $exentry
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
01150000 013bf000   notepad__   (no symbols)
```

This would still require a lot of parsing, but you can use the `lm 1m` approach as well:

```
0:000> lm 1ma $exentry
notepad__
```

Comment: just be aware that this may not scale with a kernel mode dump @$exentry will point to nt not the module of exception  kd> dx Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("!analyze -v").Where(a=>a.Contains("MODU"))
    [0x0]            : MODULE_NAME: LiveKdD
kd> lm 1m a @$exentry
nt