# How to watch a CMap (CArray) object, based on its memory address

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, mfc

I'm still working with the same script, I mentioned in [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555138/is-there-a-windbg-command-for-retrieving-the-module-name-of-a-dump).
General idea:

- open a dumpfile, using a script
- view the memory addresses of all variables
- try to get some information

This time the `dt` function seems to be failing on a `CMap` object:

```
dt <application_name>!CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64> m_nCount 000000eab8748430
Ambiguous matches found for <application_name>!CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64> (dumping largest sized):
<application_name>!CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64>::~CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64>
<application_name>!CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64>::CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64> {0x02b bytes}
```

In order to solve this, I tried to open the object in Visual Studio watch-window, but this seems to be failing, regardless of what I try:

```
(CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64>)0x000000eab8748430 => identifier "sCMap..." is undefined
(CMap)0x000000eab8748430 => identifier "CMap" is undefined
(<application_name>!CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64>)0x000000eab8748430 => identifier "<application_name>" is undefined
(mfc110u!CMap<int,int,CUIntArray * __ptr64,CUIntArray * __ptr64>)0x000000eab8748430 => identifier "mfc110u" is undefined
...
```

However this way of working seems to be working for other MFC classes, like `CStringArray`:

```
(CStringArray*)0x000000eab87c6d10 => this is giving good results
```

Does anybody know how I can show a `CMap` (or `CArray`) object in Visual Studio's watch-window, based on its memory address?

Comment: This has nothing to do with STL...

Comment: @sergiol: So? I just did a search on this webpage for STL and the first and only entry is your remark :-)

Comment: I edited your question just now to remove all STL references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the debugger has problems with the CMap definition, and by removing the `__ptr64` entries from the type definition (mind the space at the beginning of `__ptr64`), I can see the content of the variable:

```
(CMap<int,int,CUIntArray *,CUIntArray *>*) 0x000000eab8748430
```

I believe there is a bug in the debugger :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Comment: There's just one thing I haven't figured out yet: does the debugger have a problem with `__ptr64` in particular or with the fact that the type definition contains two things `CUIntArray` and `__ptr64`, that's still to be investigated, but I don't have other cases right now.